# Activity called from service

Tags: android

```java
public class oddg extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;
    int maximum ;
    private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

//      @Override
//      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//                  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
//                      
//                      moveTaskToBack(true);
//                  }
//                  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
//      }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {

        // get the increment value from the text box
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        // get the maximum value
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
        // convert the text value to a integer
            maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();

        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {

                        // enter the code to be run while displaying the progressbar.
                        //
                        // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
                        // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
                    while(dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) 
                    {
                        // wait 500ms between each update
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        // active the update handler
                        progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                    }


                }
                catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // if something fails do something smart
                }
            }
        });
        // start the background thread
        background.start();
        //oddg o1 = new oddg();

        // o1.onPause();

    }


    // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if(dialog.getProgress()== dialog.getMax())
            {

//                  Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
//              
//                  stopService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class));

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
                startService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class)); 
            }

            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: i have written this code but its nt working......occuring the application got forcefully closed dialog.please tell me whether this is write or wrng???

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustomDialogExample.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(i);



}
```

Try this and say me if it's ok ;)

Comment: hi..its nt working sir.....whether can i provide you whole Use case????so that you got to know what exactly problem is...!!!

Comment: Yes, it will be more easy if you could put more code, and especially the stack trace please.

Comment: @nanis Hi,actually i have created application it contains:- one layout on which i have two text boxs and one button.as i press on button then my progress bar got started on dialog box..and i have called to next activity(message dialog box) as progress bar got reached to maximum value dialog message is displayed.. but i want to run this in background and as i am playing with another applications then also my message dialog must displayed on current application......right now dialog message is getting popup in my application only. please help to achieve it.....

--Thanks in Advance....

Comment: // handler for the background updating
     Handler progressHandler = new Handler()
     {
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
         {
          if(dialog.getProgress()== dialog.getMax())
          {
           
//           Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
//          
//              stopService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class));
              
           Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
              startService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class)); 
          }
           
          dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
         }

Comment: public class CustomDialogExample extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 
 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/** Display Custom Dialog */
CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(this);
customizeDialog.show();
}
}

Comment: public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button okButton;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
super(context);
/** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
/** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
setContentView(R.layout.main);
okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
/** When OK Button is clicked, dismiss the dialog */
if (v == okButton)
dismiss();
}

Comment: Ok, it's very difficult to read the code like this. Could you edit your first post, and put this informations ? MoreOver could you put the stacktrace please ? Your activty doesn't have any layout ? You show directly the dialog ?

Comment: @nanis i hv put up my code of activity....i will put other dialog code in the same.after reading this...tell me after reading this....

Comment: do you have the log of crash please ?

Comment: look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html This could help you when your app crash to know where the error is. If you have myEclipse open the perspecive : Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS. and copy /paste the log please :)

Comment: @Smith, I think you should delete all these comments and concentrate on making your original question more clear.  You need to say what you are trying to do, and what exactly is going wrong.  At the moment your questions contains only code, which isn't even formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

`this` in your code refers to onClickListener not Activity, try

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(arg0)
```

or
`dialog = new ProgressDialog(oddg.this)`

or you can instantiate 
`dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);`
in `OnCreate()`